# Eclipse - Glassfish 4 Debugging startup timeout

Tags: eclipse-kepler, glassfish-4

Glassfish 4.0 final gives a timeout everytime I try to start it in Debug mode.
The normal run on server (from Eclipse) does work without a timeout.

I've tried running Glassfish 4.0 from Eclipse Juno and Eclipse Kepler, both have the correct port configuration for debugging (9009), both are failing to start Glassfish in debug.

Is this a known problem? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue with the Glassfish 4.0 adapter in Eclipse.

Here is a workaround:

- Shut down Eclipse, open a command line in the Glassfish server home directory and stop the domain:

  `asadmin stop-domain domain1`
- Start Eclipse, select 'Run \ Debug Configurations...' from the menu and bring up the 'Debug Configurations' dialog
- Find the GlassFish 4.0 application server
- Click on the 'Arguments' tab and change the VM argument to:

  `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009`
- Click 'Debug' to start Glassfish in debug mode, or use 'Debug On Server' from the servers view

Comment: Great, that worked. (for other user, note the dash should be included before the VM argument)

Comment: I have the same issue on Eclipse Juno & Glassfish 4 in normal start (run, not debug). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

After installing the last update of Glassfish tools for Kepler I got some meanfull message which actually help me solve the problem and now I can run Glassfish in debug mode.
Here is my workaround:
Go to your `.\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` folder.
Open `domain.xml` file in any desired editor.
Navigate to `./domain/configs/config[name=server-config]/java-config` node.
You should have an attribute **`debug-options`** as below:

```
debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Remove " -Xrun" and it should look like:

```
debug-options="-Xdebugjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Save. Restart/start Eclipse Kepler and should be able to run Glassfish in debug mode again, if you had similar problem like mine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed. The bug was reported here: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-370. 
You can update the plugin from update sites http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno (or kepler). I think you have to remove all old run and debug configurations and maybe to re-register the GF runtime and server again.