# Eclipse Kepler x64 debug mode tomcat not starting

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-kepler, debug-mode

I am trying to start my eclipse kepler x64 in debug mode, but it won't start.  it was running 2 weeks ago but now it won't start the debug mode.  I tried possible solution found here in stack overflow but none of them work.  Here is the error I got from the console when trying to start it in debug mode.  Using tomcat 6.  OS used in windows 8.1

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

Error on the .log file of eclipse under meta data:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2013-11-20 13:50:54.259
!MESSAGE Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Already tried reinstalling java and eclipse  and tomcat still the same error.  Can't start it on debug mode.

In the morning when I rebooted my machine and started eclipse and start it on debug it works.  Then I stopped it and then started again in debug and now it won't start.
Hoping if someone can shed some light about this. Thanks

Comment: check your ports. Typical of this kind of thing. Make sure no other program is using the required port.

Comment: I hope you were right,  But nothing is running on my machine that uses any port, right now it's just java, chrome, eclipse and mysql it's a developement machine so nothing much is running and also an antivirus.  Trying to uninstall it now to see if it's the culprit.

Comment: antivirus is probably blocking the port. Failing that, check your firewall if you have one.

Comment: Sad to say, everything was uninstalled also antivirus still it will not start in debug mode.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: And....I'm out of juice. 

Windows has the new notion of "you are no longer an administrator..you are a user". They're trying to emulate the unix / linux way...can't blame them.

Just for a sanity check, open up command prompt and run a netstat -a. Do you see your port there?

The only reason why I'm harping on about ports is because the JDWP is timing out. It's not communicating over the net..its internal so something is making it timeout...only thing I can think of is ports

Comment: also...download sysinternals. The guy who wrote this stuff discovered spyware...Microsoft quickly snapped him up.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/   It gives you a better window into your system

Comment: when I do netstat it shows 8080 and 8009 and status is listening.  From this point on I don't understand anymore what you were saying, sorry I'm kinda of a newbie.

Comment: maybe this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083811/eclipse-glassfish-4-debugging-startup-timeout

Comment: Still didn't work got this error
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    agent library failed to init: jdwp
    ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.

Comment: sounds like you need to kill the process.

Comment: I don't know what process you wanted to be killed but when I'm not doing and just open eclipse there is only one process of javaw that is running that is used by eclipse,  and when I try to start in debug mode a new one is created but when it fails to start it will just remove the new process.

Comment: are you using glass fish? Or any other server...if so, run the equivalent of the shutdown method to stop its process. You'll need to do this in command prompt.

Comment: e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gitwj.html

Comment: if its tomcat...just cd into the tomcat directory...you'll see a bin folder. Run shutdown.exe

Comment: Doint the step didn't help.

Comment: Is Eclipse pointing at your tomcat installation directory?..If you can see the "Servers" panel in eclipse...double click it...where is it pointing? You may be shutting down the wrong tomcat. Eclipse ships with its own these days

Comment: Yes it's pointing correctly to only one tomcat that is the one I installed.

Comment: When in windows...reboot. Try again lol.

Comment: @Slihp In the morning when I rebooted my machine and started eclipse and start it on debug it works.  Then I stopped it and then started again in debug and now it won't start.

Comment: Have you tried to run eclipse as an administrator?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes  it's running on administrator always, and also when I restart eclipse and then start it in debug mode for the first time it works, but when it is stopped it will never start in debug mode again unless it eclipse will be restarted back.  It's really wierd and I don't know what caused it.

Comment: When you first start as debug and it works how are you stopping it? I'm asking because, maybe, some weird thing on eclipse is lefting some open ports which could cause the problem. As you said that restarting eclipse works it must be something that eclipse has left opened.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm stopping it with the interface right click on the server icon and clicking stop.  Yes restart eclipse make the debug mode work, one time only.  I wanted to check if ports where open when server was stop using 'netstat -ano' but I couldn't find port 8080, 8005, 8009 on the list.

Comment: So Try another thing. Open your task manager and go to process tab, click on the button that it says show process from all users (something like it). Then start eclipse and see javaw.exe process PID (menu show->choose columns). Note this pid. Then start the tomcat on debug and see what is the new javaw process, after stop the tomcat see if the process goes away, if not kill it and try again to start the tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with avast, uninstalling it will not work but you need to clean it.  FOund the answer in here https://feedback.avast.com/responses/eclipse-debug-functionality-not-working-after-upgrade-to-avast-2014

Thanks for those who have helped.